# Unable to parse binding Json

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Need help with bidnings in Knockout. Im totaly newbiew on knockout.
Have tried to toubleshoot by firebug without result.

Here is my example

This is the Knockout ViewModel

```
function MarketViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.markets = ko.observableArray();

    var baseUri = 'api/market';

    $.getJSON(baseUri, self.markets);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new MarketViewModel());
})
```

The API controller that returning the array as json works perfectly btw.

And my view

```
<!-- Default datatable -->
<div class="block well">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <h5>Default datatable</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-overflow">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="data-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Marknad</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="forech: markets">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /default datatable -->

@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/vm/MarketViewModel.js"></script>
}
```

**UPDATE**

Error from firebug: Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: description is not defined;
Bindings value: text: description
This throws Unable to parse binding on the property "description" in view.
But the JSON result contains properties for description.

Json array:

```
[{"$id":"1","MarketId":14,"Description":"SE Projektutveckling","ChUser":"anders.persson","ChTime":"2013-01-28T09:07:50.067"},{"$id":"2","MarketId":39,"Description":"SE Styckehus","ChUser":"anders.persson","ChTime":"2013-01-21T23:01:04.637"},{"$id":"3","MarketId":40,"Description":"NO Styckehus","ChUser":"anders.persson","ChTime":"2013-01-21T23:00:58.01"},{"$id":"4","MarketId":41,"Description":"GB Styckehus","ChUser":"anders.persson","ChTime":"2013-01-21T23:00:50.933"},{"$id":"5","MarketId":42,"Description":"DE Styckehus","ChUser":"anders.persson","ChTime":"2013-02-05T09:39:57.03"},{"$id":"6","MarketId":43,"Description":"SE Fritidshus","ChUser":"anders.persson","ChTime":"2013-01-21T23:00:24.597"}]
```

Comment: Can you maybe post a sample json (what is printed out with: `$.getJSON(baseUri, function(data) { console.log(data);self.markets(data)});` )?  Also there is typo in your `data-bind="forech: markets"` it should be `data-bind="foreach: markets"`. Also the casing of the properties matters make sure that the result contains the property `description` and not `Description`

Comment: Please se the updated message. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property names in the bindings (and in generally in JavaScript) are **case sensitive.**

In your JSON you have have `"Description"` with a capital `D` so you need to write `"Description"` also in your binding:

```
<td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
```